# Use own TCP layer implementation with QuickFIX/J

Tags: quickfixj, single-threaded

My codebase relies on an internal TCP layer implementation which does TCP session multiplexing using a non blocking selector pattern (java.nio). This means I can create a single threaded app that can handle any number of TCP sessions.

The application I am working on should ideally be single threaded. I can't find a way to have QuickFIX/J run on the same thread my application is running on. Would there be a way for me to use QuickFIX/J only as a pure FIX protocol translator by passing the data in/out of my TCP layer into QuickFIX/J?

Comment: If you get complete FIX message Strings out of your TCP layer then take a look at QFJ's `Message.fromString()` or `MessageUtils.parse()`. I might add an answer later about the threading stuff.

Comment: BTW, QFJ uses the MINA library which also utilizes NIO.

Comment: @ChristophJohn thank you for the reply. Makes sense that QFJ uses NIO. The fact that it does doesn't seem to prevent users from having to use at least one separate thread for FIX communications though. My problem right now is that I want to build a single threaded application relying on QFJ for fix communication.

Comment: I don't know how your application looks like. If it makes use of `Executors` then you could try passing an `ExecutorFactory` into `SessionConnector.setExecutorFactory`. Also see here: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/5702022fa7c84b99ae33c8694f2e3130da4c8799/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/mina/SessionConnector.java#L104 and https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/ExecutorFactory.java

Comment: @ChristophJohn, thank you for that info. If we try to forget about my application for now, all I would want is to be able to interact with a FIX component handling session lvl state mgmt and takes `inbound bytes` or `outbound FIX app msgs` in, and spits back either `translated inbound FIX app msgs` or `serialized outbound msgs` out. This would allow me to use any independent transport layer I want (TCP or else) and also any threading model I want. Would there be a way to achieve this you think?

Comment: Btw by "inbound" I mean data coming from the Acceptor to my Initiator, and by "outbound" data sent by my Initiator to the Acceptor.

Comment: Not sure , if using the ExecutorFactory way as @ChristophJohn mentioned worked for you?  Reason is, if my app is using only 1 thread, and given QFJ uses NIO (selector based), my thread will be blocked on QFJs selector draining it from  blocking on my app's internal selector.  QFJ should be somehow exposing a way to accept apps selector too i believe